# Why the clickhouse `com.github.housepower.jdbc.ClickHouseConnection` performance is great?

Tags: clickhouse

I tried several way to import data to clickhouse. I found that the `com.github.housepower.jdbc.ClickHouseConnection.getSampleBlock` and then import data by `sendInsertRequest(Block block)`.

the performance is verfy great. anyone know the reason about it.

Answer (score 0):

Need a bit more detail here.  What are you trying to do? read data from one table and insert into another in ClickHouse?

Are you forced to use the JDBC driver? If so, some sample code would be useful.

Comment: A lot generated by my app, And I have to put these data into clickhouse . about 300w records per seconds.  not forced to use jdbc driver,  anyway can be used to insert the data to clickhouse.